# Правильно ли стоят знаки препинания в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Во всех остальных главах Вы можете следовать моим убеждениям, а можете оставаться «при своих», кроме этой – первой главы.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

**Во всех остальных главах Вы можете следовать моим убеждениям, а можете оставаться «при своих», кроме этой, первой главы.**

> Обособление уточняющих согласованных определений – явление достаточно редкое и во многом зависит от воли пишущего. Обычно определения с уточняющим значением рассматриваются как однородные, то есть запятая ставится не с двух сторон, а с одной – между определениями.
>   *Быстрыми шагами прошёл я длинную «площадь» кустов, взобрался на холм и... увидел совершенно другие, незнакомые мне места (Тургенев).*
>   ([Уточняющие члены предложения](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html))

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Моё детство и юность прошли в обстановке коммунальной квартиры, но память не сохранила негативных воспоминаний от **этой**, чисто советской реальности. [И. К. Архипова. Музыка жизни (1996)]
>   Юрий Алексеевич был родом из **этих**, смоленских мест, поэтому не раз бывал в родных краях. [И. К. Архипова. Музыка жизни (1996)]
>   И потому адвокаты Петров, Шульман и Велембицкая отбивали своих подзащитных именно по **этой**, политической линии, понимали, что в ней-то и вся опасность. [Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок (1975-1977)]

Меня смутило выражение "следовать моим убеждениям" в данном контексте. Что оно означает в данном случае? Я понимаю так. Вы убеждали автора писать определенные вещи или излагать определенным образом, а он (при написании глав) волен  следовать Вашим убеждениям или нет. Если Вы это хотели сказать, то все в порядке.

Вот пример:

> Я и многие из нашей семьи даже считали, что он втайне обратился к религии своей горячо любимой жены и своих детей, однако на смертном одре он всё же предпочел подтвердить свою верность церкви дедов и, **следуя настойчивым убеждениям своего старого друга** Э. К. Липгардта, пригласил остававшегося в единственном числе в Петербурге французского священника, отца Амодрю, который его и соборовал. [А. Н. Бенуа. Жизнь художника (1955)].

Если же Вы пишете об убеждениях как о системе взглядов, то такое употребление, на мой взгляд, проблематично. В этом смысле слова люди следуют своим (или близким им) убеждениям, а не чужим.

Далее, не вполне ясен смысл Вашего "кроме"; ясно, что в отношении первой главы у автора нет свободы выбора, но что из перечисленных двух он обязан делать: "следовать" или оставаться «при своих»? Догадываюсь, что он должен "следовать", но, на мой взгляд, лучше бы это прямо сказать в тексте.